# Postfix relay all mail through SES except for one sending domain / address

Tags: postfix

I'm thinking this is really really super simple, but I can't figure out what I need to do. I don't mess with Postfix much (Just let it run and do its thing) so I've got no idea where to even start with this.

We have postfix currently configured to relay all mail out through SES using the code below. We need to modify this so that emails sent from one of our domains (domain.com) DO NOT go through SES. Everything else should continue to flow out through the SES connection. I'm assuming this is like a one line thing but my google skills are not helping me at all.

```
relayhost = email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com:25
smtp_sasl_auth_enable = yes
smtp_sasl_security_options = noanonymous
smtp_sasl_password_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_passwd
smtp_use_tls = yes
smtp_tls_security_level = encrypt
smtp_tls_note_starttls_offer = yes
smtp_tls_CAfile = /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt
smtp_destination_concurrency_limit = 450
```

**Update** I have created sender_transport file in /etc/postfix. In it is `@domain.com smtp:` I then ran this through postmap and placed `sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_transport` above the above block of code and restarted postfix, but still all email is going out through SES.

**Log after sending**

```
Oct 22 14:38:48 web postfix/smtp[19446]: 4B19D640002: to=<kevin@mydomain.com>, relay=email-smtp.us-east-1.amazonaws.com[54.243.47.187]:25, delay=1.4, delays=0.01/0/0.92/0.44, dsn=2.0.0, status=sent (250 Ok 00000141e21b181f-ee6f7c4f-f0f5-4b0f-ba69-2db146a4f988-000000)
Oct 22 14:38:48 web postfix/qmgr[19435]: 4B19D640002: removed
```

I don't think this log is what you're looking for, but it's the only thing that is logged when mail goes out, and this is with me running /usr/sbin/postfix -v start manually and not with the init script.

Comment: Post the complete logs of ONE mail sent with the above in place.

Answer (score 1):

The parameter you need is [**sender_dependent_default_transport_maps**](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#sender_dependent_default_transport_maps):

```
sender_dependent_default_transport_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/sender_transports
```

The above file should contain something like:

```
@thatdomain.example.com    smtp:
```

Don't forget to [**postmap**](http://www.postfix.org/postmap.1.html) the file.

Reference: the [**relayhost**](http://www.postfix.org/postconf.5.html#relayhost) documentation.

EDIT:

I see you also require smtp encryption for all outgoing traffic.
This will not work when the relayhost is not always used.

Far better to make Amazon the exception (this will make sense later) and apply the relayhost and TLS to that one transport only.

For now, just set

```
smtp_tls_security_level = may
```

to test if it works.

Comment: I've managed to stumble this far just now but it's still not working. All email is still going out via SES. I placed the sender_dependent.... line above the above block of code. Should it be below it? I think I'm close but the above block is overriding this line.

Comment: The order of configuration parameters has no impact on postfix, except if you were to define one before you use it.

Comment: That's what I thought, but for some reason the line is having 0 impact.

Comment: I've posted a log, but it doesn't have much information in it.

Comment: The block is literally copy and pasted from Amazon's setup instructions. They require encryption for all of their connections. I just set smtp_tls_security_level = may and restarted postfix. No change, emails still going out through SES.

Answer (score 0):

This is 5 years down the line but perhaps still helpful for others that stumble across the post. What you are looking for is the *relayhost_map* option. With this you are able to specify which domains **are** able to relay mail through SES, the rest will try to use local delivery.

In your /etc/postfix/**main.cf** file you specify the following to use the relayhost_map option:

```
sender_dependent_relayhost_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/relayhost_map
smtp_sender_dependent_authentication = yes
```

- **remove or comment out the line: *relayhost =***

Then you create the file /etc/postfix/**relayhost_map** and specify each domain that is allowed to relay via SES for example:

```
@domain.com        smtp-server:port
```

Lastly update your /etc/postfix/**sasl_password** file to have the same structure and include the same domains:

```
@domain.com        username:password
```

Hash the files and restart postfix:

```
postmap hash:/etc/postfix/relayhost_map
postmap hash:/etc/postfix/sasl_password
systemctl restart postfix
```

Just repeat for each domain that needs to relay through SES (or any other relay server), on it's own line in both the relayhost_map and sasl_password file.